# Unity - resolving without resolve()

Tags: c#, .net, unity-container, enterprise-library, ioc-container

I would like to just markup a property with an attribute [DoInjection] and have unity do the injection. I don't want to have to use prop = Unity.Resolve(type). Thats a pain and messy. Does unity provide attributes to do this or do I have to build my own?

Edit: register in App.Main

```
ISessionFactory sf = new SessionFactory();
            container.RegisterType<IRepository, CustomerRepository>(new InjectionConstructor(sf.CurrentUoW));
            container.RegisterInstance<IUnitOfWork>(sf.CurrentUoW);
```

Using [Dependancy] on IUnitOfWork propery in ClassX other class but it's always null. Do I need to build ClassX instance using Unity to get this to work? It looks like I do have to. I don't like that.

Comment: I updated my answer with some additional information about setting things up in a console app since it sounds like that might be where you are running into trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unity has a `DependencyAttribute` you can use for this:

```
public class MyObject
{
  private SomeOtherObject _dependentObject;

  [Dependency]
  public SomeOtherObject DependentObject 
  {
    get { return _dependentObject; }
    set { _dependentObject = value; }
  }
}
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650198.aspx

Based on your question, it sounds like you might be trying to use Unity in the wrong spot and your design sense was telling you it didn't feel right. You should only see Unity where you bootstrap your application. That's your Main method in a console app or Global.asax in a web or wcf app. The idea is to keep relying on dependencies all the way up the chain until you get to where you bootstrap and resolve just that one top level object using your IoC container. In a console app, I do this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var container = new UnityContainer())
        {
            container
                .AddExtension(new ConfigureForConsole(args))
                .Resolve<MyApplication>()
                .Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

http://www.agileatwork.com/console-application-with-ioc/

In this case, `MyApplication` is my top level object (it doesn't need to be an interface here). The `ConfigureForConsole` is just a one-off custom container extension that has all the `RegisterType` lines in there. Alternatively you could initialize the container from App.Config here. The idea though is that your Main method has almost nothing in it. Another benefit of this approach is that it makes your code more portable. I find that console apps usually turn into windows services and keeping things clean here makes that transition pretty painless.

Comment: Yes, you need to resolve ClassX with Unity in order for it to set the IUnitOfWork property

Comment: I want to define the types and instances to use one time and from then one never both with a container or resolve() call again. You're saying I have to build my objects (ClassX) which have dependencies using a container so that the dependencies will be resolved. So my code will be littered with Resolve<T>() calls.

Comment: See my updated answer. You should only see Resolve<T>() in one spot in your application.

Comment: Why would I see it only one time? Each time I needed to spin up a new instance of ClassX I would have to use Resolve<T>(), would I not?

Comment: If you need to create instances on demand, then I recommend injecting  a simple Factory that is just a thin wrapper around Unity. You should really try to avoid having any reference to Unity other than where you wire up your application. With more details I can give you a more specific answer...

Comment: @Michael, I found http://blog.vuscode.com/malovicn/archive/2008/05/18/design-for-testability-microsoft-unity-part-7.aspx which helps me to understand your comment. The level of abstracting in the code is just ridiculous.